# rich:progressBar currentValue does not working with For-Loop?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, progress-bar

In RichFaces 4.1, rich:progressBar 'currentValue' from the ManagedBean does not updating with for-loop.

progressBar.xhtml

```
 <h:form id="formProgress">
        <h:commandLink action="#{progressBarBean.startProcess}" value="click here"/>

        <rich:progressBar mode="ajax" value="#{progressBarBean.currentValue}" interval="1000" id="pb"
            enabled="#{progressBarBean.enabled}" minValue="0" maxValue="100">

            <h:outputText value="Retrieving #{progressBarBean.currentValue} of #{progressBarBean.totalRecords}" />
        </rich:progressBar>

    </h:form>
```

Bean

```
package ap;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProgressBarBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8775622106408411357L;


        private boolean enabled = false;

        private Integer totalRecords;
        private Integer currentValue;;

        public String startProcess() {
            setEnabled(true);
            setTotalRecords(100);
            return null;
        }

        public Integer getCurrentValue() {
            if (isEnabled()) {
                for(currentValue=0;currentValue < totalRecords;) {
                    currentValue++;
                }
            }
            return currentValue;
        }

        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return enabled;
        }

        public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
            this.enabled = enabled;
        }

        public Integer getTotalRecords() {
            return totalRecords;
        }

        public void setTotalRecords(Integer totalRecords) {
            this.totalRecords = totalRecords;
        }
}
```

When i click the 'click here' link, the currentValue updates very fastly and reaches the totalRecords to 100 suddenly. It was not updating in the incremental way(present value in for-loop). The progress bar is not updated by the present value return by the method.

Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems: your Java code does not do what you want it to do and you're not telling the page to update (that won't happen automatically).

Take a look at the `getCurrentValue()` again: It increments `currentValue` from 0 to 100 and returns the result which is 100. `#{progressBarBean.currentValue}` does not care (or know) what happens with the variable, it only cares about the result of the `getCurrentValue()` method.

So in order for it all to work it will have to look like this:

### Page

```
<a4j:commandLink action="#{progressBarBean.startProcess}" value="click here" render="pb" execute="@this"/>
    <rich:progressBar mode="ajax" value="#{progressBarBean.currentValue}" interval="1000" id="pb"
        enabled="#{progressBarBean.enabled}" minValue="0" maxValue="100">
        <a4j:ajax event="begin" listener="#{progressBarBean.increment}" render="text"/>

        <h:outputText value="Retrieving #{progressBarBean.currentValue} of #{progressBarBean.totalRecords}" id="text" />
    </rich:progressBar>
```

The `a4j:ajax` is fired each second (i.e. each interval), it increments the `currentValue` and updates the text.

You also need `a4j:commandLink` (or `a4j:ajax` inside the `h:commandLink`) in order to rerender the progressbar - in your example you enable the progressbar in the bean but the value on the page does not change.

### Bean

```
public Integer getCurrentValue() {
    return currentValue;
}

public void increment() {
    if (isEnabled() && currentValue < totalRecords) {
        currentValue++;
    }
}
```

Ask if anything isn't clear.

Comment: The above solution is working if we are using 'if' condition and to increment the currentValue++. But when we are using the 'for-loop', it was not working. for(currentValue = 0; currentValue < totalRecords;) { currentValue++; } . Kindly check with for loop please.

Comment: If you want it to work with the for-loop you would have to make the loop pause after each increment and have another method get the current value. There are ways to do that but I really wouldn't recommend it.